# Zend Ajax can't delete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a table named `state` with columns `state_id`, `state_name`. Currently I can add new states and edit them, but I can't delete states. What might be wrong with my code?

```
{title:"Actions",template:'<a class="left" onclick="javascript:openEditStatePopup(this);">Edit</a>' + 
    '<a class="right" onclick="javascript:deleteState(this);">Delete</a>'
    ,width:120,sortable:false}
```

This snippet is the view code, and when I click the link, it executes the following JavaScript:

```
function deleteState(element)
{
    var countryDetail = {};
    var GriddataItem = $("#state_grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(element).closest("tr"));
    countryDetail.state_id =GriddataItem.state_id;
    countryDetail.state_name = GriddataItem.state_name;
    // alert(countryDetail.state_id);
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?= $this->baseUrl('admin/state/delete')?>",
        data: {state_id :  countryDetail.state_id},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        failure:function(){
            alert('not working');
        }
    });
}
```

When I echo `alert(countryDetail.state_id)` before the `$.ajax` call, I can get the correct state id.

My delete controller is:

```
public function deleteAction()
{

    $state = $this->_request->_getPost('state_id');
    $stateMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_StateMapper();
    $stateMapper->delete($state);
}
```

and the model mapper for deleting is:

```
public function delete(Application_Model_State $state)
{
    $data = $state->toArray();
    $adapter = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->delete(array('state_id=?'=>$data['state_id']));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to write `deleteAction` as following

```
public function deleteAction()
{


    $state = $this->_getParam('state_id');
    $stateMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_StateMapper();
    $stateId = $stateMapper->delete($state);
    $this->_helper->json(array('success'=>1));
}
```

Comment: @zlipper as per your problem what ever is their in the above code the same i mentioned in the answer. `$this->_helper->json(array('success'=>1));` has nothing to do with delete. It states that i need not to waste that much time for your problem. @lordkelvin can you please explain that how can you delete a record using `$this->_helper->json(array('success'=>1));`

Answer (score 0):

in your controller action `deleteAction()` you are getting POST param 'state_id'

```
$state = $this->_request->_getPost('state_id');
$stateMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_StateMapper();
$stateMapper->delete($state);
```

and you are passing that `$state` in the `$stateMapper->delete($state);` function

in your model class function `public function delete(Application_Model_State $state)` definition you are passing State model object not and state id, so you should change this to

```
public function delete($state_id)
{
    $adapter = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->delete(array('state_id=?'=>$state_id));

}
```

Then it should work...

Another thing I have not seen

```
failure:function(){
      alert('not working');
}
```

Rather it is

```
error:function(){
    alert('not working');
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried your solutions is not working...is that i define $.ajax correctly..?

Comment: @zlippr I have changed the answer, check again

Comment: yes i already change failure to error..when i tried your solutions
the error function is execute...do you need more info about the script..?

Comment: use firbug extension and check does ajax able to reach that url, change `url:"<?= $this->baseUrl('admin/state/delete')?>"` and try to give it manually for debugging and then try again

Comment: checked with firebug..the url is executed and data is passed properly..but still i got not working message..do you think json expect any return..?

Comment: what you are getting in the response? Any error? Because if your ajax is sent properly then it must return some response.

Comment: when using firebug i set breakpoint at the $.ajax function for delete, when it reach success: function(){ it skip the content and jump to error:function(){

Comment: Do not put any break point let ajax run and before that open firebug and goto net panel -> xhr tab and see what response you are getting. tell me that response otherwise if ajax fail it will give you `500 Internal Server Error` and line text will get red colored

Comment: ok if i do edit a stuff in similar way the response i receive is {state_id:1}
  state_id: "1"
similarly with delete it goes to error page, but the above solution only can be seen if in controller updateAction has 
$this->_helper->json(array('state_id'=>$stateId));

Comment: @zlippr, sorry as I am not able to help you but at last check that your delete function working fine without ajax, if it does then try with ajax and it should work fine.

Comment: $this->getDbTable()->delete(array('state_id = ?' => $state_id)); this code is the solutions that i finally found !!!

Comment: The same I posted in answer... Check it. U can mark solved if you found solution.